# Android NETWORK_PROVIDER returns null. Until Phone Restarted

Tags: android, android-location

I am finishing an Android application in which I am observing location changes from gps and network providers.  My problems is that I have enable both providers properly and I am requesting location updates from each provider. (I am testing on actual phones not a simulator to clarify.)  GPS works flawlessly the majority of the time unless I can not get a gps lock(This is expected). I have been racking my brain over why network location are returned null on some phones some of the time and only seem to begin receiving location updates for "network" after phone has been restarted (Not ideal). I have wifi enabled.  All the correct permissions Internet,coarse and fine. Gps updates are working just fine.  I have tried removing updates from the listener and then requesting again after a set time of receiving null. I have seen this on the S3, One X, galaxy nexus, and a Motorola Droid M. At first I thought it was a hardware issue.  Seems like some of the posts out here are related to the same topic.  I just want to see if anybody out there has come across a fix or a work around?